# Creating paypal app as a developer for a customer

Tags: paypal

I am integrating Paypal chained payments for one of my customers.

for test purpose, I created an application through my Paypal account,
but the money obliviously needs to be transferred to his Paypal account,
though I don't want the money to go from my account to his..

Is it enough to specify his account email address as a receiver in my code,
or should I insist on opening an application through his Paypal account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on exactly what you're doing you should be able to set him as the receiver and that would be fine.

I still generally recommend that people setup their own app, though.  That way if you are hit by a bus (knock on wood) their stuff isn't stuck in your developer account.

If you are building an app that you will maintain and will have lots of people using then I would stick to your own account and everybody would just use that.

If it's an app that only that client will use, though, I would recommend having them create their own app.